# Females are not required to wear headgear with the "mess" and evening "mess" uniforms, or

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [military] Females are not required to wear headgear with the **mess** and evening **mess** uniforms, or with the Army blue or white dress uniforms to an evening social event.

What's the mess?

**not to be closed**

mess is worth apprciating because it's very polysemic and also very specific at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dining hall in a army or aboard a ship. Also used for the people who eat in this place.

There are different messes for different groups of personnel, like the Soldiers' Mess or the Officers' Mess.

In this case they seem to be taking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mess_dress_uniform

Comment: 'mess uniform' is a uniform military personnel wear when they go to a social event where foods and drinks are provided and full of coworkers. The mess uniform is semi-formal.